# EventBus not working when trying to communicate between two fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, communication, greenrobot-eventbus

I have three fragments in a viewpager set up like a sliding tab layout. I need to pass a string value from one fragment to another.

First, I tried setting up an interface like the answers here suggest [How to pass data between fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194548/how-to-pass-data-between-fragments) 
which did not work for me. The idea is that Fragment A tells the Main Activity and then the Main Activity tells Fragment B.

So I looked for different answers

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/06/communication-between-fragments-in.html

Looked promising but didn't work because I couldn't use the same functions with my code since I set up my viewpager with google's slidingtablayout instead of the old actionbar.

Now I've stumbled upon EventBus. And I really think this is my answer. I added it to my code just as both below answers suggest. Nothing crashes, but nothing works either.

I find this in the logcat:

D/Event: No subscribers registered for event class tk.abestudying.atob.TextChangedEvent
D/Event: No subscribers registered for event class de.greenrobot.event.NoSubscriberEvent

[Communication between Fragments in ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20474695/communication-between-fragments-in-viewpager/20475430#20475430)

[Communication between SlidingTabLayout tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31588024/communication-between-slidingtablayout-tabs)

Here is my code:  Link removed

Please help. I have been trying out solutions for hours, but I am stumped. Thank you.

Edit: I got it working by being cautious and rewriting code.

Comment: Using `EventBus` seems like an overkill for this. If you haven't given up on `Interface`s yet, here a very simple and very elaborate explanation and example on **Inter-Fragment Communication** on YouTube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GDHnIZEJ76I. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Elvis, but I managed to get EventBus working perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the `@Subscribe` annotation.  According to the [`README`](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus), a subscribing method should look like this:

`@Subscribe
public void onEvent(AnyEventType event) {/* Do something */};`

Comment: @Subscribe was not needed. I just rewrote my code while being extremely cautious and I got it working. There was a sneaky problem with one of my layout files. Thank you..

Comment: @Abe Any idea what the sneaky problem was? I might be experiencing that now.