# Radio button pass data in fragment

Tags: android, radio-button, fragment

I have some RadioButton in fragmentA,,,and also some RadioButton in fragmentB 
i want that when one of these `isChecked`(FragmentA),in FragmentB disable all radio button.
same activity  host these fragment.

event click Radio Buttons in Fragment A:

```
   RadioGroup radioGroup = view.findViewById(R.id.readingGroup);
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, @IdRes int i) {
            switch (i) {
                case R.id.btnNormalD:
                    //code
                    break;
                case R.id.btnAbsence:
                    //code
                    break;
                case R.id.btnWithAnObstacle:
                    //code
                    break;
                case R.id.btnHaunted:
                    //code
                    break;
                case R.id.btnDestroyed:
                    //code
                    break;
                case R.id.btnNoSubscribersFound:
                    //code
                    break;
                case R.id.btnGround:
                    //code
                    break;
                case R.id.btnInterrupted:
                    //code
                    break;

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Basic Communication between two fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700798/basic-communication-between-two-fragments)

Answer (score 0):

If your fragments share same container except `ViewPager` then You can pass data between fragments using `Bundle`.
Whenever you making transaction set the state of radio buttons to bundle and validate it into next fragment .

```
 Fragment fragment=new FragmentA();
    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
    bundle.putBoolean("show",false);// Pass the data here
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(fragment,R.id.frame).commit();
```

And you can get this in next  fragment .

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_2,null);
    if(getArguments()!=null){
        boolean show=getArguments().getBoolean("show",true);
        if(show){
            // Do action here 
        }else{
            // Do action here
        }
    }
    return view;
}
```

If you are using `ViewPager' then you can simply get the fragment from adapter and call any public method of this fragment to set the state .

Comment: my fragments don't have id,because these Initialize in view pager adapter

Comment: What do you mean  don't have id? Are you developing for tablet?

Comment: these base on `int position` in view pager are in position(`public Fragment getItem(int position)`).

Comment: Ohkk . have a look into [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20474695/communication-between-fragments-in-viewpager).

Comment: @ADM hey, if I want to click fragment's radio button then FragmentB's LinearLayout will be visible. is it possible to make? how can I implement it? guide me, here is the where i posted it, please.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68063328/checked-radiobutton-in-onefragment-to-anotherfragment